# How do I report a bug in Ubuntu translation?

Tags: launchpad, bug-reporting, translation

I am familiar with reporting bugs on launchpad, but have no idea on how to report a bug in the translation.

- Should I file it against the package that contains this bug, or should I report it as a but in some translation-project?
- How to make sure the translators team will get notified?
- What information should I include in such a bug report?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/HowToTriage#Translation_Bugs_and_Launchpad_integration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two useful links.

1. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/Triage#Translation_bugs_and_Launchpad_integration
2. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#Filing_a_translation_bug